# Jquery partial load in symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony

i am trying to get twig template via partial load.

Here is controller:

```
public function kategoriAction()
{
    $kategori = new EmlakKategori();
    $form = $this->createForm(new EmlakKategoriType(), $kategori);

    return $this->render('CompanySiteBundle:Admin:kategori.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

And here is template:

```
                <li><a href="#">Emlak Ekle</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Emlak Sil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Emlak Özellik Ayarları</a></li>
                <li><a href="#kategori" id="kategori">Kategori Ayarları</a></li>


            <div class="col-md-8" id="content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#kategori").click(function(){
            $("#content").load("{{ path('kategori') }}");
        });
    });
</script>
```

When i click to #kategori link, i get 200 OK but page does not load into the #content div.
What is my fault?

Answer (score 0):

For testing you could change it to

```
$.get("{{ path('kategori') }}", function(data){
    $("#content").html(data);
});
```

then you can set a break point, maybe you can see the problem.

Comment: thanks for answer, how can i set break point? i'm not familiar.. Thanks.

Comment: you can use the dev tools from chrom or firefox. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: ah ok, im using firebug.. but it gets 200 OK, but nothing loads